# Android ViewPager Loading fragments in wrong sequence

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a spinner having values from week 1 to 12. On selection of any week from spinner, 7 fragments(starting from sunday to monday) are loaded in my viewpager and tablayout. The only difference is in data for each week and day.

Now the issue is for each week correct data is populated in sunday fragment. When I slide to monday fragment the data populated there is of tuesday and so on.

Below is my viewpagerAdapter class

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager, 1);
    TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout)  mView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager, position + 1);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, int weekNo) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    final SunFragment sunFragment = new SunFragment();
    Bundle sunBundle = new Bundle();
    sunBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    sunFragment.setArguments(sunBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(sunFragment, "Sunday");

    final MonFragment monFragment = new MonFragment();
    Bundle monBundle = new Bundle();
    monBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    monFragment.setArguments(monBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(monFragment, "Monday");

    final TuesFragment tuesFragment = new TuesFragment();
    Bundle tuesBundle = new Bundle();
    tuesBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    tuesFragment.setArguments(tuesBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(tuesFragment, "Tuesday");

    final WedFragment wedFragment = new WedFragment();
    Bundle wedBundle = new Bundle();
    wedBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    wedFragment.setArguments(wedBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(wedFragment, "Wednesday");

    final ThursFragment thursFragment = new ThursFragment();
    Bundle thursBundle = new Bundle();
    thursBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    thursFragment.setArguments(thursBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(thursFragment, "Thursday");

    final FriFragment friFragment = new FriFragment();
    Bundle friBundle = new Bundle();
    friBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    friFragment.setArguments(friBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(friFragment, "Friday");

    final SatFragment satFragment = new SatFragment();
    Bundle satBundle = new Bundle();
    satBundle.putInt(DayFragment.KEY_WEEK_NO, weekNo);
    satFragment.setArguments(satBundle);
    adapter.addFragment(satFragment, "Saturday");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Fragments are loaded in below sequence:

> when sliding Right
>
> fragment -> data loaded
>
> sun        sun
>
> mon        tues
>
> tues        wed
>
> wed        thurs
>
> thurs        fri
>
> fri        sat
>
> sat        sat
>
> when sliding left
>
> fragment -> data loaded
>
> sat        sat
>
> fri        thurs
>
> thurs        wed
>
> wed        tues
>
> tues        mon
>
> mon        sun
>
> sun        sun

Comment: Creating Fragments each time spinner item is selected is heavy and costly. Instead i would create them once, then send some data through some Eventbus (or interface callback) to fragments when item is selected, so each fragment will refresh itself

Comment: Hey, thanks I will change that. Still a beginner so learning and doing things right now.

Comment: 7 fragments from Sunday to Monday? not true? it should be starting from Sunday, ends on Saturday, the other thing is, you need to post the relative code from the fragment that have problem (the part where you calculate days or so ).